# Is it possible to automate group assignment to Azure AD Enterprise Applications (specifically AWS SSO)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

In Azure AD, I have an Enterprise Application setup for SSO access with AWS.

Is it possible to programmatically assign security groups to an Enterprise application?

It isn't clear how this would be possible with either Terraform, az cli, or PowerShell modules. Users and groups are successfully being provisioned in AWS IAM and IdP-initiated SSO login works just fine, so I'm confident that the enterprise application is setup correctly.

Here are images of my enterprise application

[image]

and adding a group to it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Graph Service Principals API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0) to do this. Each enterprise application is Service Principal with its [appRoleAssignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0).

To create a new assignement tied to a security group, you can use [Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) like below.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}/appRoleAssignedTo
{
  "principalId": "{resource id - Security Group ID in your case}",
  "resourceId": "{servicePrincipalId}", // service principal/entreprise app id
  "appRoleId": "{The default app role ID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) or your app role id}" // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approle?view=graph-rest-1.0
}
```

If this option work for you then you can use the MS [Graph PowerShell SDK command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/powershell/get-started) New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignedTo.